# Connecting ubuntu server to the internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I recently installed Ubuntu server on my old laptop and I am trying to set up a private web hosting here (mostly as a learning experience). However, I am unable to connect the server to the internet. Can someone please help me out?
The steps I took:

1) Edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and added:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid WIFI-NAME
wireless-essid WIFI-PASSWORD
```

2) Ran `/etc/init.d/networking restart` --> Nothing happened
3) Then I created a file `wpa.conf` with the following details

```
network={
    ssid="networkname"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=WPA
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=TKIP
    psk="networkpassword"
}
```

4) Then ran `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
This gives some more errors such as

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

but finally manages to establish a connection

```
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xxx completed
```

For the first time it ran properly. After my server was idle for a while, it disconnected and isn't working now. I have an IP address (shown by `ifconfig`), `dhclient wlan0` returns `File exists` but nothing works.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your access point is using WPA rather than WEP (I hope it is - WEP security is poor), then you need to change the keywords in the /etc/network/interfaces file accordingly:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid WIFI-NAME
wpa-psk WIFI-PASSWORD
```

A `wpa.conf` file should not be necessary AFAIK.

Comment: Does defining these details in the `interfaces` file be enough for connecting to the ip? I mean if I just restart the service it would connect? Also, can I specify multiple wifi's to try from the same port? (As in wlan0 with multiple wpa-ssids)